# How to catch facebook api post errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post to Facebook pages and groups from a dynamically populated list of data with checkboxes. I have reached the stage where I have got the access token, page id etc and the posted data just before making the Api post call.

However, the call fails. Meaning, it does not post to the page. Actually the script does not seem go beyond

> $publish = $facebook->api(....

The Code

```
<?php
    echo "<h3>Submitted for post</h3><img src='$fbimg' width='150' height='150'><br>$title<br>$postpage<br>$descr<br><br>";

    echo "Page_id : $page_id <br> access token : $page_token <br>app Id : $config[appId]<br><br>";
//try{
    $publish = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post',
     array('access_token' => $page_token,
    'message'=> $title,
    'from' => $config['appId'],
    'to' => $page_id,
    'caption' => 'Marathi Christian Matrimony',
    'name' => 'Marathi Christian Matrimony',
    'link' => $postpage,
    'picture' => $fbimg,
    'description' => $descr
)); 
//}

//catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    //echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
        //$previousException = $e->getPrevious();
           // Do some further processing on $previousException
        //       exit;
            //}

    if($publish){echo "Published total $totpost posts!";}
    else{echo "NOT PUBLISHED !";}
?>
```

I am not too good at error catching with 'try/catch'. Though I was trying to use it and didn't see any difference. So commented it out.

The code does not reach the if($publish) part. So no echoing of my error messages.

Is there an issue in the code ? How can I find what is the error ?

What other information is required to resolve this issue ?

Comment: You only tried to catch exceptions of one specific type - so if it throws any other type, it will still be uncaught.  Catch all exceptions, not just those of a specific type: `catch (Exception $e)`

Comment: And FYI: You can not specify title, description, thumbnail, caption dynamically any more, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations Facebook will read all that information from the Open Graph meta data your posted URL returns only.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the input. I did try using Catch as you mentioned. Still no go. And as for the details that cannot be dynamically specified, How can I then automate random posting from my database ? Should I just leave these out from the API call ? And let the url do the work ?

Comment: By the way, could the issue of not posting  have anything to do with permission scopes ? I have used Publish_pages, Publish_actions and manage_pages. And I have read the fb docs which says these are not deprecated

Comment: I think it is because, I removed the Publish_actions - which requires a facebook review ! Now it works !

Comment: Hey @CBroe , FYI  I  am able to specify title , description etc and it is properly getting posted as specified ! I am using the latest API version 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer to the exact question. Though I couldn't catch the error, a bit of hard research on facebook calls found me the solution to my issue of not being able to post to facebook page.

The reason was the scopes. I was using publish_actions scope along with manage_pages and publish_pages scopes. Publish_actions require a facebook review! I removed it and now it posts like a charm !